# application.worksheetfunction with another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

Is it possible to use functions this way but referring to another workbooks? I recently had to go through many different folders and files to collect data, it is working with VBA already, but I'm pretty sure my code is verbose with things I don't need. Columns are not in the same position so I was thinking of using `Index(match())` to get the column address.

I was doing this:

```
Cells(StartRow, Counter).Formula = "=iferror(MATCH(""ColumnName"",'" & FullPath & "[" & File & "]SheetName " ,0),0)"
```

It works, but then I have to work with the number returned to figure out the column.

Answer (score 0):

If you write `=INDEX(A1:D4,MATCH("Feb";A1:D1,0),MATCH("Tues",A1:A4,0))` you will get "4". Hope it helps.
[image]

Comment: yeah, but I meant is a search in another workbook. My VBA is already working fine, I was just wondering if it is possible to go to another spreasheet, find the correct column and doing the calculations without having to write the formula in a range.